# remove div-col-md-4 in rows first position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 12 blocks in my html page and I have 4 images in each row.
But I want to remove block 10 and 13 keeping their position empty and in responsive I dont want that empty space: look for the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZVxr.png)

here is the link to code pen https://codepen.io/rahulv/pen/mwEQJo

```
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
```

I want to use a blank space instead of position 10 and 13. position 11 and 12 should be in center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified your codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/weWQmG

**Updated from your comment:**

Added css class to 10 and 13 .show-small
And add to css:

```
.show-small{
  visibility: hidden;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
  .show-small{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: ya this work but in normal view I dont want to display 10, 13 period but my 11 and 12 should be in same position
I want to use a blank space instead of position 10 and 13. position 11 and 12 should be in center

Comment: so if i'm getting you correctly... you want 10,13 hidden on tablet/desktop view but show in mobile view. I updated the codepen

Comment: i think i got what you're looking for. See updated codepen

Answer (score 0):

Use col-md-3 or col-lg-3. That way, the columns will only show up in larger displays.

[Here](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) you can see which screen sizes correspond with which size prefixes. -sm- refers to screens over 768px wide. Presumably the mobile phone you're using has at least that many pixels and therefore the columns show up on it.

Comment: I want to use a blank space instead of position 10 and 13 position 11 and 12 should be in center